# Units used in X-ray energy spectrums

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, x-rays

I am trying to understand the X-ray emission spectrum based on medical X-ray tubes and there are several variants of the graph function given in several books as in this image:

[image: image link here]

At a specific energy (in KeV) the plot shows the number of photons emitted by an element in the units of $Hash/ [KeV*cm^2 *mAs]$ where $Hash$ is the numeric value of the number of photons.

My question is regarding the units of the dependent variable of the graph function. How is there a $KeV$ unit added to it?. Shouldn't the number of photons have the units of $Hash/ [cm^2 *mAs]$ where, the photons cross an area over a particular current-time product and therefore $cm^2*mAs$ in the denominator is understood but why a KeV term(unit) is also present?

Comment: what you really see there is a spectral distribution function - the total intensity is $I = \int I(E) dE$. So the integral takes care of the energy dimension.

Comment: Yes, I would get the total number of photons if I do  $∫I(E)dE$ but if I want to know the number of photons at a specific energy, the units makes no sense to me.

Comment: there is no "number of photons at a specific energy". For that, you can either remember your calculus (a single number has a Lebesgue-measure of zero) or (with more handwaiving) the Heisenberg uncertainty principle (there is never a absolutely discrete energy). See also robs great answer.

Comment: Very similar to (duplicate?): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334970/why-do-we-plot-distributions-histograms-etc-per-logarithmic-interval-i-e-pe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the way to read your "hash" ("#") is as "[number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)."

What you've plotted here is a differential spectrum: the number of x-ray events observed in each energy window from $E_i$ to $E_i + \Delta E$.  The most common way to construct such a spectrum is to build a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).  But in a histogram, the number of events in each bin depends on the width of the bins, $\Delta E$.  For example, if you start with a histogram that has 100 energy bins, decide it's too noisy, and combine the odd bins with their even neighbors to produce a new histogram with 50 bins, the number of events in each bin will approximately double.  But you haven't changed your *data*, in that case, just your *representation* of that data.

You can avoid that blurring between data and representation by displaying, rather than raw counts per bin, the counts divided by the bin width.  In our $100\to50$ rebinning example, the number of counts in the larger bins would approximately double, but the width doubles as well: the differential spectrum doesn't change.

Essentially, each point in your spectrum here is 
$$
\frac{dN}{dE\cdot dA \cdot dt\cdot dI}
$$
where the integral of this spectrum, $N$, is the total number of events you'd expect from the experiment.  You're not bothered by the fact that if you ran the experiment twice as long, or used a detector with twice the area, or drove twice as much current through the source, that you'd double the number of photons you find.  For energy the relationship is nonlinear: the total number of events is $N = \int \frac{dN}{dE} dE$, and what's plotted here is the differential $dN/dE$.

I learned this as a graduate student when I tried, unsuccessfully, to turn a plot of neutron flux versus wavelength, $dN/d\lambda$, into a plot of neutron flux versus energy, $dN/dE$, using the de Broglie relation $p = h/\lambda$ and the kinetic energy $E = p^2/2m$.  You can't just re-map the points on the spectrum to the new values; you have to take into account that the denominator is different as well in order to have the two spectra integrate the to same $N$.